# ¿Qué significa un ampersand en la declaracion de una función?

Tags: php

El siguiente código parece hacer lo mismo con y sin ampersand(**&**):

```
<?php

class Cartera {

    public $dinero = 93;

    public function &muestraLaPasta() { // Si quito este ampersand
        return $this->dinero;
    }

}

$carteraDeMaria = new Cartera;
$miPastaGansa = &$carteraDeMaria->muestraLaPasta(); // y este
echo $miPastaGansa;                // el resultado es el mismo

?>
```

Tanto si los dejo como si los quito el resultado es el mismo, imprime 93. ¿Para qué sirven?

Gracias a la respuesta de Ivan Botero se que esa función devuelve una referencia.
Pero parece que no es una referencia capaz de sobrevivir por si misma. Si la asigno a una variable esa variable contiene el valor no la referencia, pese a que lo que le he asignado es el resultado de esa función, que se supone que es una función que devuelve una referencia.

```
<?php
class Cartera {
    public $dinero = 93;

    public function &muestraLaPasta() { // Esta función devuelve una referencia
        return $this->dinero;
    }
}

$carteraDeMaria = new Cartera;
$miPastaGansa = $carteraDeMaria->muestraLaPasta(); // Parecería que almaceno esa 
                                                   //referencia en una variable
echo $miPastaGansa . "\n";                // el resultado es el mismo

// Cuanto dinero tiene Maria
echo $carteraDeMaria->dinero . "\n";

// Cuanto dinero tiene Maria ahora
$miPastaGansa = 5000; // Pero las modificaciones a través de esa referencia 
                  // almacenada en esta variable
echo $carteraDeMaria->dinero . "\n";  // No se propagan
```

Creo que hay todavía algún detalle fino de esa referencia devuelta por la función que se me escapa.
¿Como es que tengo que usar otro **&** antes de asignarla? Parecería que entonces tengo una referencia a la referencia a dinero. En vez de simplemente una referencia a dinero, que es lo que quiero.

Comment: En este [enlace] [http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.return.php], se encuentra el siguiente texto: **Para usar la referencia retornada, se debe usar la asignación por referencia**. Es decir, tanto en la declaracion como en el llamado a la funcion, siempre se debe usar ampersand.

Comment: Creo que es a eso a lo que te refieres?

Comment: @IvanBotero Pues sí a eso me refiero. Entonces es una cuestión de diseño del lenguaje. Me resulta raro que para asignar el resultado de la función por referencia a una variable haya que usar & pero no haya que hacerlo para pasarlo a una función que espera una referencia. Pero, en fin, así han hecho el lenguaje.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Para empezar.

Debemos tener claro qué es una **referencia** en PHP.

De acuerdo a un pequeño fragmento en la [documentación oficial de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign).

> Las referencias de PHP permiten hacer que dos variables hagan referencia al mismo contenido.

Miremos este ejemplo:

```
<?php

$variableA = "Hola mundo!";
$variableB = $variableA;

$variableA = "Hola amigos!";

print "A: " . $variableA . "\n";
print "B: " . $variableB . "\n";

?>
```

El resultado que obtendremos será:

```
A: Hola amigos!
B: Hola mundo!
```

Pero ahora, agreguemos un ampersand (&) a nuestro codigo y miremos qué ocurre:

```
<?php

$variableA = "Hola mundo!";
$variableB =& $variableA;       /* Agregamos el & */

$variableA = "Hola amigos!";

print "A: " . $variableA . "\n";
print "B: " . $variableB . "\n";

?>
```

El resultado que obtendremos será:

```
A: Hola amigos!
B: Hola amigos!
```

### ¿Qué nos quiere decir esto?

Hemos usado un operador para acceder al mismo valor de otra variable y usarlo, lo hemos modificado, pero al modificarlo se modificó el valor de la variable original, en este caso `$variableA`.

```
$variableB =& $variableA;
```

**Esto se conoce como [Asignación por referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign).**

---

### En ese orden de ideas

Podemos ver un ejemplo sencillo de una **función** usando las **referencias**:

```
<?php

function caminar($X){
    $X++;
}

$pasos = 0;

caminar($pasos);
caminar($pasos);
caminar($pasos);

print "He caminado $pasos pasos\n";

?>
```

El resultado de este programa será:

```
He caminado 0 pasos
```

Y volvemos a usar el operador ampersand (&) y veremos como ocurre la magia.

```
<?php

function caminar(&$X){             /* Agregamos el & */
    $X++;
}

$pasos = 0;

caminar($pasos);
caminar($pasos);
caminar($pasos);

print "He caminado $pasos pasos\n";

?>
```

Y el nuevo resultado es:

```
He caminado 3 pasos
```

Al igual que el ejemplo anterior, lo que hemos hecho acá es **pasar una referencia** a una variable externa a la función, y a través de esa referencia la **hemos modificado**, incrementando su valor en cada llamado a la funcion `caminar()`.

**Esto lo conocemos como [Paso por referencia](http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.pass).**

---

### Por último

> El operador ampersand (**&**), delante del nombre de una función, **retorna una referencia**, en lugar de un valor.

Esto se conoce como **[retorno de referencias.](http://php.net/manual/es/language.references.return.php)**

---

#### ¿Esto qué significa?

Miremos este ejemplo:

```
<?php

$variable = "StackOverflow";

function &obtenerReferencia(){
   global $variable;   
   return $variable;
}

$puntero = &obtenerReferencia();
$puntero = "Stack Overflow Rules!";

print $variable;

?>
```

Hemos inicializado el valor de `$variable` con el texto "StackOverflow", pero cuando ejecutamos el programa, obtenemos el siguiente resultado:

> Stack Overflow Rules!

Lo que ha ocurrido es que en la variable `$puntero` hemos **guardado una referencia** a la posición en memoria de la variable `$variable`, que contiene nuestro texto original. Al obtener la referencia a dicha variable hace que **cualquier cambio que hagamos en la misma afecte a la variable original**.

---

*He hecho una modificación a tu ejemplo, respondiendo a la pregunta de por qué imprime lo mismo*:

```
<?php
class Cartera {
    public $dinero = 93;

    public function &muestraLaPasta() { // Si quito este ampersand
        return $this->dinero;
    }
}

$carteraDeMaria = new Cartera;
$miPastaGansa = &$carteraDeMaria->muestraLaPasta(); // y este
echo $miPastaGansa . "\n";                // el resultado es el mismo

// Cuanto dinero tiene Maria
echo $carteraDeMaria->dinero . "\n";

// Cuanto dinero tiene Maria ahora
$miPastaGansa = 5000;
echo $carteraDeMaria->dinero . "\n";

?>
```

Obtenemos como resultado:

```
93
93
5000
```

#### ¿Qué ocurrió aquí?

Al imprimir el valor retornado de una función de referencia `muestraLaPasta()`, el valor quedará siempre intacto. Lo que cambia es el origen de ese valor, en ese caso, he agregado este par de líneas:

```
$miPastaGansa = 5000;
echo $carteraDeMaria->dinero . "\n";
```

Modificando la referencia de ellas `$miPastaGansa`, que para este caso es un "puntero" hacia el atributo `$dinero`. Lo que nos dará posteriormente el valor de 5000, cuando obtengamos el valor del atributo `$dinero`.

Comment: Yo creo que deberías leer sobre variables por referencia y variables por valor así como su paso en forma de parámetros a funciones pero para C++ en donde verás un término llamado `puntero` que es en esencia lo que PHP o Java quieren hacer cuando usas POO, pero como en PHP o en Java no existen punteros la teoría explicada se te volverá muy abstracta. Lo que se hace es apuntar a la misma dirección de memoria es por ello que al cambiar el valor por alguna de las referencias todas las otras también cambian. Saludos

Comment: @Hoscanoa Si, claro que lo he leido, es por ello que la variable donde hacia los ejemplos se llama `$puntero`, y por ello lo explico como *"es un 'puntero'"* ya que estos lenguajes no cuentan con punteros de manera nativa, sin embargo gracias por el apunte.

Answer (score 8):

En realidad se puede aportar poco a la excelente respuesta dada.

Quiero aportar una explicación visual de lo que ocurre con las referencias.

Como se ha dicho, las referencias en PHP permiten usar dos variables para referirse al mismo contenido. Para ello se usa el signo *ampersand* (`&`), cuando estudié mecanografía le llamaban: *"y" comercial*.

**Las referencias en PHP no son punteros**, como ocurre en otros lenguajes, sino que serían como aliases de tabla de símbolos.

Comenzamos...

---

#### `Caso 1:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`Código:`**

```
//Caso 1:

$x = "original"; //Creamos una variable $x con el valor "original"
$y = &$x;        //Creamos una referencia de $x llamada $y

//Resultado

echo "\nCaso 1:\n\n";
echo "Valor de x: ".$x."\n";
echo "Valor de y: ".$y."\n";
```

**`Resultado:`**

```
Caso 1:

Valor de x: original
Valor de y: original
```

---

#### `Caso 2:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`Código:`**

```
$x = "original";     //Creamos una variable $x con el valor "original"
$y = &$x;            //Creamos una referencia de $x llamada $y
$y = "NO original";  //Cambiamos el valor de $y, y en consecuencia, el de $x

echo "\n\nCaso 2:\n\n";
echo "Valor de x: ".$x."\n";
echo "Valor de y: ".$y."\n";
```

**`Resultado:`**

```
Caso 2:

Valor de x: NO original
Valor de y: NO original
```

---

#### `Caso 3:`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`Código:`**

```
//Caso 3:

$x = "original";     //Creamos una variable $x con el valor "original"
$y = &$x;            //Creamos una referencia de $x llamada $y (aquí $y="original")
$z = "extraño";      //Creamos una variable $z con el valor "extraño"
$y = &$z;            //Hacemos que $z haga referencia a $y. Y $x recupera su valor "original"


//Prueba

echo "\n\nCaso 3:\n\n";

echo "Valor de x: ".$x."\n";
echo "Valor de x: ".$x."\n";
echo "Valor de z: ".$z."\n";
```

**`Resultado`:**

```
Caso 3:

Valor de x: original
Valor de y: extraño
Valor de z: extraño
```

Cuando se desactiva la referencia, simplemente se rompe el enlace entre el nombre de la variable y el contenido de la variable. Esto NO significa que el contenido de la variable será destruido, por eso, `$x` recupera su valor original al romperse la referencia.

---

#### `Caso 4:`

Si se desea romper la referencia, el modo correcto es usando `unset`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**`Código:`**

```
//Caso 4:

$x = "original";     //Creamos una variable $x con el valor "original"
$y = &$x;            //Creamos una referencia de $x llamada $y (aquí $y="original")
unset ($y);          //Rompemos la referencia
//echo $y;           //Si hacemos esto tendríamos un aviso: PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: y

//Prueba

echo "\n\nCaso 4:\n\n";

echo "Valor de x: ".$x."\n";
echo (isset ($y) ? "y está definida\n": "y no está definida\n");
```

**`Resultado:`**

```
Caso 4:

Valor de x: original
y no está definida
```

---

#### `Caso 5:`

Trataremos de romper la referencia asignando `null` a la variable `$x` y luego asignándole un nuevo valor. Veamos lo que ocurre:

**`Código:`**

```
//Caso 5:

echo "\nCaso 5:\n\n";

$x = "original";      //Creamos una variable $x con el valor "original"
$y = &$x;             //Creamos una referencia de $x llamada $y (aquí $y="original")
$x=null;              //Asignamos null a $x

echo "\nCon null la referencia se rompe 'temporalmente':\n";
echo (isset ($x) ? "x está definida\n": "x no está definida\n"); 
echo (isset ($y) ? "y está definida\n": "y no está definida\n"); 
echo "\n";


$x="OTRO original";   //Asignamos un nuevo valor a $x
echo "\nVeremos que y adquirirá el nuevo valor asignado a x:\n\n";

echo (isset ($x) ? "x está definida\n": "x no está definida\n");
echo "Valor de x: ".$x."\n";

echo (isset ($y) ? "y está definida\n": "y no está definida\n"); 
echo "Valor de y: ".$y."\n";
```

**`Resultado:`**

```
Caso 5:

Con null la referencia se rompe 'temporalmente':
x no está definida
y no está definida


Veremos que y adquirirá el nuevo valor asignado a x:

x está definida
Valor de x: OTRO original
y está definida
Valor de y: OTRO original
```

---

El demo completo de los diferentes casos, [se encuentra aquí](http://rextester.com/LGUC19395).

Comment: Leer el Caso 5 me da dolor de cabeza. Está claro que Dios hizo el php para fastidiar a la humanidad :). Excelente respuesta pese a la maldad divina.

Comment: Excelente respuesta, tendras que explicarme una cosa mas....Como hiciste para generar esos graficos de las explicaciones? Que herramienta usaste?

Comment: @JoseAntonioDuraOlmos creo haber leído que, a partir de una versión de PHP que ahora no recuerdo, si usamos `Clases` evitaríamos todo esto, y el uso de la **fea** _y comercial_ o _ampersand_  en nuestras funciones y variables. Pero no me detuve a profundizar en el tema.

Comment: @IvanBotero usé simplemente Pages,  o sea, el Word de Apple y luego hice captura de cada imagen. Tomó poquísimo tiempo y, que conste, no soy diseñador gráfico. Son sólo cuadros con texto dentro y relleno de fondo.